# Powershell, output xml to screen

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm learning PowerShell.  I can load an xml file into a variable and manipulate it.  I can then call the object's save method to save to disk.  I expected there to be a way to output the resulting xml to screen, though.  I can't seem to find one.  Is there a way, other than outputting to file and then file-to-screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [PSCX module](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx). You will find `Format-Xml` cmdlet that does exactly that.

Example:

```
Import-Module pscx
$xml = [xml]'<root><so><user name="john">thats me</user><user name="jane">do you like her?</user></so></root>'
Format-Xml -InputObject $xml
```

will produce:

```
<root>
  <so>
    <user name="john">thats me</user>
    <user name="jane">do you like her?</user>
  </so>
</root>
```

For more info look at `help format-xml -full`

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it should allow for nice formatting even without embedded whitespace.  If you don't want to install an extension, and you have all the whitespace in there, use empo's answer instead.

Comment: +1 for this. There are many great things in the PSCX module, didn't realize this was in there. It's worth installing if you're a PS user and haven't installed it yet.

Answer (score 59):

I couldn't get the Community Extensions to work and I don't really want to have to install something extra anyway. I have found another approach on a Microsoft blog -

```
function WriteXmlToScreen ([xml]$xml)
{
    $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter;
    $XmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter;
    $XmlWriter.Formatting = "indented";
    $xml.WriteTo($XmlWriter);
    $XmlWriter.Flush();
    $StringWriter.Flush();
    Write-Output $StringWriter.ToString();
}

$xml = [xml]'<root><so><user name="john">thats me</user><user name="jane">do you like her?</user></so></root>'
WriteXmlToScreen $xml
```

Comment: Great solution. The function name is misleading... it doesn't have anything to do with a screen, `Write-Output` makes standard function output so you can capture in a variable `$formatted = WriteXmlToScreen $xml`, or pipe somewhere `WriteXmlToScreen $xml | Out-File $f`

Comment: This solution was easier and less intrusive than downloading the PSCX module. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use this function with XML elements, remove the `[xml]` datatype from the function declaration (ie. `function WriteXmlToScreen ($xml)`), otherwise PowerShell assumes that the variable is an XML document and displays the error: "Cannot convert value "System.Xml.XmlElement" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".

Comment: If you're using this function for displaying (debugging) XML within a function change `Write-Output` to something like `Write-Host`

Answer (score 24):

The only way I know is using `System.Xml` properties like `outerxml` or `innerxml`. These properties should have code already indented as long as the source was.

Comment: One note on something that confused me at first.  I had to set `$xmlObject.PreserveWhitespace = $true` (where xmlObject is your variablename) _before_ loading the xml data into `$xmlObject` in order to get the newlines and indents of the original.

Comment: Indentation should be indipendent from `PreserveWhitespace`. May be become relevant when outputting onto the screen.

Comment: It appears so.  Without `PreserveWhitespace` the output to screen looses most returns and indents where save-to-file keeps them.  Except for returns and indents that are part of inner text, it looks like.Oddly, with my test file, when saving to file one of the tabs got turned into two spaces, but the other tabs were fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Xml.OuterXml).ToString()
```

Comment: If the `Linq` assembly isn't available, load it beforehand with: `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithpartialName("System.Xml.Linq") | Out-Null`

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution I've found is using [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Parse_System_String_) like this:

```
Write-Host ([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse("$(Get-Content -path 'c:\myxml.xml' -Raw)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I wanted to share my hackish answer.  I needed to send the xml to php and I couldn't send anything else.

the answer I came up with was to save the file to disk and then run a get content on it.  This echoes back the xml text and nothing else:

```
#hack alert.  
#we need to echo out just the text of the XML back to PHP. 

IF ("$env:TEMP\xml.xml") {Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\xml.xml"}
#$xmlDoc.Save("c:\temp\xml.xml")
$xmlDoc.Save("$env:TEMP\xml.xml")
get-content "$env:TEMP\xml.xml"
```

In my case I was sending it back to PHP and it worked perfectly

Comment: [@samaspin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22639013/1098603) should have done the trick...